# PHP dynamic library error php_curl.so

Tags: php, zend-framework, debian, dynamic-library

I am trying to run the zf.sh (Zend tool) script to create a new Zend project but I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.iso' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.iso: cannot open     shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I ran an ls -la of that directory and have:

```
16:31.57 [00h00m00s] root@vps:/usr/lib/php5/20090626# ls -la
total 752
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Sep 11 15:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Sep  3 10:34 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67936 Aug 23 15:16 curl.so <---- Curl installed
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116856 Aug 23 15:16 gd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47280 Aug 23 15:16 mcrypt.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135864 Aug 23 15:16 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55424 Aug 23 15:16 mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31120 Aug 23 15:16 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100776 Aug 23 15:16 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 166496 Aug 19  2010 suhosin.so
```

in my PHP ini file (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)

I have:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Why am I getting the above error. I am running a Debian server :)

Comment: Open a terminal in that folder and write this: cp curl.so php_curl.so ????

Comment: I know it is looking for php_curl and not curl but how do I get passed this error?

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution but tried that and it didn't work :/

Comment: What error shows now??

Comment: same one :/

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.iso' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.iso: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: But now the file php_curl.iso exists ....check perms on that file

Comment: Have you tried using the `absolute path` to the file?